# Efficient way to loop through a column

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a dataset look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'stringID':['AB CD Efdadasfd','RFDS EDSfdsadf dsa','FDSADFDSADFFDSA']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
data['Index1'] = [[3,6],[7,9],[5,6]]
data['Index2'] = [[4,8],[10,13],[8,9]]
```

[image]

And i calculated a volumn based on values in Index1 and Index2 (both are list), i was using indexes to slice substrings from stringID column. Currently here is my calculation and result:

```
data['Value1'] = [data['stringID'][i][data['Index1'][i][0]:data['Index2'][i][0]] for i in range(0,len(data['stringID']))]
```

[image]

It works, but if i loop it through a large dataset it's very slow. What would be better ways to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you cosidered using apply? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: Thanks on the idea, yep that's the way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:

As you said your real dataset has more than 3 columns, you just need to slice 3 columns before getting numpy nd-array as follows:

```
data['Value1'] = [x[y[0]:z[0]] for x, y, z 
                           in  data[['stringID','Index1','Index2']].to_numpy()]
```

---

You can't avoid loop. However, you may simplify your list comprehension using numpy nd-array as source to speed it up such as

```
data['Value1'] = [x[y[0]:z[0]] for x,y,z in data.to_numpy()]
```

---

**Timing on 300K rows** :

```
data = pd.concat([data]*100000, ignore_index=True)

In [1380]: %timeit [x[y[0]:z[0]] for x,y,z in data.to_numpy()]
617 ms ± 24.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [1382]: %timeit  [data['stringID'][i][data['Index1'][i][0]:data['Index2'][i][0]] for i in range(0,len(data['stringID']))]
11.3 s ± 320 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, it is about 18 times faster than your solution.

Comment: Can you help explain what is x in this case? thank you

Comment: @April: it is just a variable name I chose to hold value unpacking from each row. If you want more verbose, it's gonna to be this: `[sID[ix_1[0]:ix_2[0]] for sID, ix_1, ix_2 in data.to_numpy()]`. So, `sID` is `stringID` value, `ix_1` is `Index1` value and `ix_2` is `Index2` value

Comment: Ah ok, i think i didn't get how you packed the variables as i got error of too many values to unpack.

Comment: @April: how many columns in your real dataset? if you have exact 3 columns as in the sample, there should be no error.

Comment: I do have more columns in my real dataset

Comment: @April: ah, in that case, you need to slice before getting numpy nd-array as follows: `[sID[ix_1[0]:ix_2[0]] for sID, ix_1, ix_2 in data[['stringID','Index1','Index2']].to_numpy()]`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DataFrame.apply`

```
data['Value1'] = data.apply(lambda d: d['stringID'][d['Index1'][0]:d['Index2'][0]], axis=1)
```

---

You can pre-process the index to use for slicing in another column

```
from operator import itemgetter

data['slice'] = list(zip(data['Index1'].apply(itemgetter(0)), data['Index2'].apply(itemgetter(0))))
data['Value1'] = data.apply(lambda d: d['stringID'][slice(*d['slice'])], axis=1)
```

Or store the slice object directly in the other column

```
data['slice'] = list(map(lambda x: slice(*x), zip(data['Index1'].apply(itemgetter(0)), 
                                                  data['Index2'].apply(itemgetter(0)))))


data['Value1'] = data.apply(lambda d: d['stringID'][d['slice']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you! And i like how you preprocess index list to make the calculation more clear. Thanks!